# RVM setting incorrect environment path

Tags: rvm

I was having trouble installing rvm on WebFaction, so I tried just copying over the `.rvm` directory with my rubies and gems. This has mostly worked. rvm works, it’s referencing the correct ruby, and the correct gem. The problem it seems, is rvm is looking for an environment file in the wrong place. It’s trying to use:

```
/Users/jezen/.rvm/environments/ruby-2.0.0-p247
```

Whereas it *should* be using:

```
/home/rekyl/.rvm/environments/ruby-2.0.0-p247
```

Where can I set the correct path?

Answer (score 0):

check `/Users/jezen/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p247/ruby` but also `/home/rekyl/.rvm/environments/ruby-2.0.0-p247` is relevant, make sure all environment variables point to proper path:

```
env | grep rvm
```